# How Arabic text in Application

Tags: blackberry-10

Hi I am new to Blackberry 10 platform and I am developing an application in Arabic language. I don't know how to display Arabic text in my application. But in Blackberry site there is some information about displaying Arabic text by changing the locale but I didn't get anything. Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to already be familiar with [BlackBerry's](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_platform/internationalization/index.html) page about internationalization. You should also take a look on the [Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/internationalization.html) page.

You should start by focusing on the in-app text:

- In the qml files, use `qsTr("A string")` instead of `"A String"`
- In the C++ files, use `tr("A string")` instead of `"A String"`

  - `tr()' is part of QObject, so it only works for classes that herit`QObject`. There are workarounds.

In Momentics, open the BAR application descriptor file, named bar-descriptor.xml file, and in the localization tab, add all the locales you want to support.

[image: Momentics Locale Editor]

Then, clear and rebuild your project. The build process should create `.ts` files in the translation directory that match the project name, but have the locale code as suffix.

The `.ts` file should be updated everytime you build your application for missing translations.

This `.ts` file is an xml file that matches what’s in the source file (`.cpp` or `.qml`) with what should be displayed on screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.0" language="fr_FR">
<context>
    <name>Page</name>
    <message>
        <source>Like</source>
        <translation type="unfinished"></translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

The following code should aready be in your main.cpp, it make sure that your applications tries to find a suitable translation for your application. Change your device locale, reload your application, and every translatable text should be loaded from your `.ts` file.

```
// localization support
QTranslator translator;
QString locale_string = QLocale().name();
QString filename = QString( "ProReader_%1" ).arg( locale_string );
if (translator.load(filename, "app/native/qm")) {
    app.installTranslator( &translator );
}
```

Beware, there is a known limitation of Momentics that prevents it from finding source files that aren’t in root subdirectories. You will have to update your .pro file :

```
lupdate_inclusion {
    SOURCES +=  \
        $$quote($$BASEDIR/../assets/qml/*.qml) \
        $$quote($$BASEDIR/../assets/720x720/qml/*.qml) \
        $$quote($$BASEDIR/../src/*.cpp) \
        $$quote($$BASEDIR/../src/app/*.cpp) \
        $$quote($$BASEDIR/../src/feedreader/*.cpp) \
        $$quote($$BASEDIR/../src/feedreader/storage/*.cpp) \
        $$quote($$BASEDIR/../src/piwik/*.cpp)
}
```

Comment: "In Momentics, open the .bar file, and all the locales you want to support." i didn't understand this statement how add locales in .bar files

Comment: @PranavJDev I was meaning the the BAR application descriptor file (bar-descriptor.xml), also added screenshot to clarify.

Comment: I have done all these steps but my phone (Blackberry Q10) does not shows Arabic text. I display the text in default(English) language.

Comment: Are the '.qm' files on the target, is the target configured with the good system language ? Maybe that's an issue with the arabic setting, try to put the arabic translations into that language and try again. Then step-by-step main.cpp to see if the the file get correctly loaded.

Comment: any way by using trUtf8("arabic string") display text in arabic language from CPP file.So I am accepting this as answer.